# Google Fonts won't load when using KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, google-font-api

I'm having trouble with getting my Google Font to load. I have tried to get it to load with the three different methods, standard, @import and JavaScript, but with no result to follow. Although if I run a tween with the KineticJS framwork the font load at the same time and looks just fine.

My code looks something like this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Hanalei::latin' ] }
    };
    (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
        '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
    })(); </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.5.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 600
    });

  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var text1 = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    text: 'Test',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Hanalei',
    fill: 'black'
  });


  layer.add(text1);
  stage.add(layer);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with FontAwesome. Here is my solution:

```
//wait for fontawsome to load
setTimeout(function(){
   kineticStuff();
}, 500);
```

No need to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnnyJS says, you must let your fonts fully load before using them.

By setting `wf.async='true'` you are telling the browser to continue loading Kinetic while it downloads the font in the background.

Therefore your kinetic text is rendered before the font is available.

You can set `wf.async='false'` and webfontJS will wait for the font to load before continuing to load Kinetic.

Therefore the font will be fully loaded and available when kinetic.text needs it.

However, with wf.async='false' the browser is halted while the font loads.

If you want to use async, you should define the `active` callback in WebFontConfig.

The `active` callback is triggered after the font is fully loaded.

So you would begin building your kinetic.text in response to that callback, knowing the font was fully available.

Answer (score 0):

Use event `onload` before initialise the stage.

(u need the fonts actually loaded in the page for kinetic drawin 'em on the canvas.)

as you asked i load images in some great way that i found a long time ago.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;

    for (var src in sources) {
        numImages++;
    }
    for (var src in sources) {
        images[src] = new Image();
        images[src].onload = function() {
            if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                callback(images);
            }
        };
        images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
}
function initStage(images) {
// create awesome stuff....
}

sources = {
brain: "res/brain.png",
f_body_blue_glow: "res/f-body-blue-glow.png",
f_body_blue: "res/f-body-blue.png",
f_body_green: "res/f-body-green.png"
}
loadImages(sources,initStage);
});
```

This is specifically for images but i think with little modifications it will be for any asset, hence use jquery's `$.get()` for the google font, and in the handler call the callback (ex. `initStage()`)

Good luck.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, as can't get it to work. I'm not sure what I precisely have to do with the code. I tried making the javaScipt to a function, and then used 'onload' in the body tag with that function (like this: 'onload="myFunction"'). Actually that just made iit a bit worse, as some of my tweens stopped working (my actual code i a bit more complicated than the example above, although that is the essens of the problem). So it would be great if you could explain in little more detail what i actual have to do.